# LibGdx fonts have stripped lines

Tags: fonts, libgdx

Im a begginer in LibGdx development and im making a simple android game. The problem I have is this:
Im creating all assests in pixel style. They are roughly 38x64 in dimensions. Then i use the otro camera to blow the image up to fit the screen while preserving rough edges. The problem i have is that since everything gets blown up the fonts do too. In the image you can see the font having like a gradient black stripes ( due to being blown up i presume ). Does enyone know how to fix this problem?

http://postimg.org/image/vj589msqn/
(cant post images)

Im sorry for my bad english and ty for you help.
good day.

PS. the font im using:

http://www.1001freefonts.com/karmatic_arcade.font

PSS. this is the code:

```
gen = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("arcade.ttf"));
font = gen.generateFont(10);
font.getRegion().getTexture().setFilter(TextureFilter.Nearest, TextureFilter.Nearest);
font.setColor(Color.valueOf("211f1f"));
font.draw(batch, "Tap red bombs", blu.W/2 - font.getBounds("Tap red bombs").width/2, blu.H/2 - font.getBounds("T").height/2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try out distance field fonts.

https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/DistanceFieldFonts

They might look intimidating to implement at first, but are really easy once you try it out. They scale up really nicely and should solve your problem.

Good luck.